# php script outputs raw HTML but only after editing

Tags: php, html, regex, render, strip-tags

i'm working on a php forum script not my own.

the forum's index page displays the topic's title and description.

i set the topic description to equal the topic's body(the actual post text), so when the topic gets posted the body gets inserted into the description field and it displays as expected, in other words, the html renders in the description area. then i click on the edit buttton for the topic which allows the title and description to be edited.
regular HTML for the description is present, i click save. the html gets inserted into the DB as regular HTML. the index page now displays the raw html instead of rendering it as it did before.

i can't figure out why it would render the first time but not after it passes through the edit code even though nothing is changed and the html is not being replaced or stripped.

i need some help and clues on what to look for and research. i've covered htmlspecialchar, strip tags and some preg replace but i'm not getting anywhere. even if i just get a clue in the right direction.

thank you much.

Comment: we can't figure out why it is not working if we don't see the code

Comment: likely, the value of the text field in the "edit" form is being escaped at some point. you'll have to track down what happens to it after the form is submitted. if you 'view source' on the page that is displaying raw html, you will prob see `lt;` instead of < in the text

Comment: i can't post the code. i was hoping for some ideas on how such a thing could happen in theory or principal, then i would go researching along those lines.

Comment: thank you danyamachine. that was enough to set me off on how to convert the html back into regular characters, which led me to the function htmlspecialchars_decode that worked! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is i needed to add the function  htmlspecialchars_decode to the relevant string.